# I cannot get toastr to be displayed using angular 6 after form submission

Tags: angular

I cannot get toastr notification to work after login form is submitted using Angular6.
Am learning how to integrate Toastr using Angular6 source: **http://technoidlab.com/angular-6-toastr-notifications-module/**

The article requires running

```
npm install ng6-toastr-notifications --save
```

and I have done that and set all the configurations at the **app.module.ts.** when I compile the app, it was a success.

My problem is that I cannot get Toastr to be displayed once the login form is submitted.  Is there any html tag elements 
that I need to set at login.html components

if I move this code below inside `logincall()` function it will display error **unexpected ';' during compilation**

```
// set toastr
 showSuccess(position: any = 'top-left') {
        this.toastr.successToastr('This is success toast.', 'Success!', { position: position });
    }
```

**//login component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Login } from '../models/login';
import { LoginService } from '../service/login.service';

import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrManager } from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-new',
  templateUrl: './login-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-new.component.css']


})
export class LoginNewComponent implements OnInit {



login = new Login('', '');
  wrong ='';
  error = '';
  success = '';


  constructor(private loginService: LoginService,  private router: Router, public toastr: ToastrManager) {}


// set toastr
 showSuccess(position: any = 'top-left') {
        this.toastr.successToastr('This is success toast.', 'Success!', { position: position });
    }



  ngOnInit() {}



public loginCall(lg) {
          this.resetErrors();
          this.loginService.logdb(this.login)
            .subscribe(
      res => {

if (res.message === 'success') {
// this.success = 'Login successful';

/*


// set toastr
 showSuccess(position: any = 'top-left') {
        this.toastr.successToastr('This is success toast.', 'Success!', { position: position });
    }


*/

                }

                // Reset the form
               lg.reset();
              },
              err => this.error = err
            );
    }


  private resetErrors(){

     this.success = '';
    this.wrong = '';
    this.error   = '';
  }

}
```

**//login component.html**

```
<div id="theForm">
  <h2>The form</h2>
  <form #lg="ngForm" name="theForm" (submit)="loginCall(lg)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="username"
            [(ngModel)]="login.username"
            #loginUsername="ngModel"
            required
            pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$">
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="loginUsername.errors?.required && loginUsername.touched">
        The username is required
      </span>
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="loginUsername.errors?.pattern && loginUsername.touched">
        The username can only contain the letters a-z or A-Z
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password"
            class="form-control"
            name="text"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="login.password"
            #loginPassword="ngModel">
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="loginPassword.errors?.required && loginPassword.touched">
        The password is required
      </span>
    </div>

<div *ngIf="success" class="alert alert-success">{{success}}</div>
    <button
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        [disabled]="lg.invalid">Login Now</button>
  </form>
</div>
<br><br><br>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { appRoutes } from './routerConfig';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ToastrModule } from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { LoginNewComponent } from './login-new/login-new.component';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
 LoginNewComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,

RouterModule,
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})


export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the  BrowserAnimation module import in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw9ulg

Comment: Thanks Mr Suresh. It now works when I click on the submit button but my real purpose of add toastr was to display the toastr alert after the submission form is successful. please can you help me futher. This is where I want it to display in the login component.ts   if (res.message === 'success') {
// this.success = 'Login successful';




// set toastr
 showSuccess(position: any = 'top-left') {
        this.toastr.successToastr('This is success toast.', 'Success!', { position: position });
    }




                }

Comment: wrap the code inside setTimeout(()=>{ this.toastr.successToastr('This is success toast.', 'Success!'); }, 400);

Comment: Thanks Mr. Suresh